# Increasing network throughput by cutting routes

Tags: graph-theory, scoring-algorithm

Suppose we model traffic flow between two points with a directed graph. Each route has either a constant travel time or one that linearly increases with traffic. We assume that each driver wishes to minimise their own travel time and we assume that the drivers form a Nash equilibria. Can removing a route ever decrease the average travelling time?

Note that the existence of multiple Nash equilibria makes this question a bit complicated. To clarify, I am looking for a route removal that will guarantee a decrease in the average traveling time regardless of the Nash equilibria that are chosen before and after.

Comment: Seeded question

Comment: The "how long it takes" for everyone on the route can depend on the number of people taking that route, I presume?

Comment: @Shreevatsa: You are right - I mistated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form this question is usually asked is whether adding a route can increase the average traveling time, and this is known as [Braess's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess_paradox).  The Wiki article gives an explicit example in which the travel time on some of the routes depends on the traffic.